# Preserve Document IDs while copying document from one site collection to another

Tags: document, document-id

Can we preserve the document ID assigned to a document while moving it from one document library in one site collection to another document library in other site collection?

I searched for some answers but they all suggest that the ID is preserved in MOVE operation but not in COPY.

I want to preserve the ID in COPY action.

Is this possible?

Comment: Why preserve the docid from a copy? This will cause conflicting behaviour. In the source site collection it will redirect you to the item in that site collection. In the new site collection it will redirect you to a search page as there are effectively 2 or more items with the same docid.

Answer (score 1):

No.

The document-ID is only maintained when using the Content and Structure page '/_layouts/15/sitemanager.aspx?Source={WebUrl}_layouts/15/settings.aspx'. Or when you create custom (Visual Studio) solution and using code.

Using 'Send to', 'Copy' or 'Move' from the ribbon will in all cases generate a new Document-ID in SP2013.

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible. [Please see this link](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/0f75f62b-ad25-43ea-88a4-5eb21fdc70b7/document-id-moving-across-the-site-collection?forum=sharepointsearchprevious).

Answer from link:

> According to your description, my understanding is that you want to
>   preserve the Document ID when moving the documents across site
>   collections.
>
> Per my knowledge, the document id will be preserved when the document
>   has been moved from one Site Collection to another Site Collection.
>
> During move operations, SharePoint Server 2010 keeps the document ID.
>   During copy operations SharePoint Server 2010 assigns a new document
>   ID. You can control this by setting a Boolean operator on the
>   PersistID column.

Comment: no Not for Moving, I want Preserve it when Copying.

for example if in Site A a Doc has ID A110 then while copying it to Site B the ID should be preserved as A110 only, moreover there should be a prefix attached to the copied document i.e. P-A110

Comment: I have gone through this link, but this is not my case, its for moving and i want the same thing but on Copying.

Answer (score 0):

Documents can be sent across sites, site collections or even across SharePoint farms using a send to connection which you can configure in central admin.   Copying a document using a send to connection will preserve most metadata including the Document ID however it will update metadata such as Modified By and Modified Date.

Note that copying a document in Explorer View will always create a new Document ID unless you have implemented your own code to handle the process.

[Copy a file to another library or Send To location.](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Copy-a-file-to-another-library-or-Send-To-location-0bfe3b52-db99-44ed-91c7-140aa9ba3d41)